# Extract contacts in DistList with Powershell from Outlook 2010

Tags: list, powershell, outlook, extract, contacts

Goodmorning everybody, and thanks for your attention.

I've a problem with importing contacts (that are into groups) from Outlook 2010. 
After connection to Outlook and Exchange, and the select of the folders (all public folders), i cannot see all the lists contacts for some lists.

This is the connection to Outlook and it seems working.

```
$Outlook       = New-Object -com Outlook.Application 
$Namespace     = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
$PublicFolder  = $Namespace.Folders.Item("Public folders - name@domain.com")
$PublicFolders = $PublicFolder.Folders.Item("All public folders")
$SharedContactsFolder = $PublicFolders.Folders.Item("myfolder")
```

And now.. the problems..

```
$DLArray = @()  
$ItemsArray = @()
$ItemsArray = $SharedContactsFolder.Items | ToArray
```

In ItemsArray i need to have all the contacts of myfolder, that are divided in **IPM.Contacts and IPM.DistList**
ToArray is a function that force items into an array, and it works good.
The problem appears with and without ToArray function, so it isn't the main cause.

I can access to contacts into the first 15 lists in **$ItemsArray**, after i see only the names of lists but i cannot extract contacts from there, using directly **$SharedContactsFolder.Items** there aren't improvements.

Properties like **.Members and .OneOffMembers** works only for the first 15 lists.

Is not an array problem, because using directly **$SharedContactsFolder.Items[1]** doesn't works anyway.

Thanks a lot to everybody, sorry for my englis that's no good.

Comment: can you try this `$arr = $SharedContactsFolder.Items | Select *`

Comment: I did, but still not working.
It's like if the list object was empty

Comment: i have it, and i can read some lists (with their contacts) but only 15/67

Comment: No, it seems empty

Comment: But in Outlook the list isn't empty, there are the contacts